# How to grep on last column only?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, grep

I have a sometextfile.txt with '|' as delimiter.

I would like to `grep` the value from last column only which consist of word "apple". How do i do it?

```
column1|column2|column3|column4|column5|column6|column7
aaaaaaa|bbbbbbb|ccccccc|ddddddd|eeeeeee|fffffff|apple
```

and grep whole row to a Newfile.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another `awk` approach:

```
awk -F\| '$NF ~ /^apple$/' infile.txt >toOutput.txt
```

Comment: that works but in english, "consist of" means "equals", not "contains".

Comment: any better enhancement? @cas

Comment: This will also accept `pineapple` or `apples`

Comment: @user6308605 AFSHIN's answer is almost the same as mine except that it uses a `~` regexp match rather than a strict `==` equivalence match (so will, e.g. also match `pineapple` and `apples`, and anything else containing `apple`).    You weren't 100% clear on this so that may or may not be what you actually want.   ASHFIN's version also relies on the default/implicit action of awk (which is to print the current line), while mine has `{print}` explicitly in the script - that makes no real difference, I only included `print` in mine to make it clearer what the script is doing.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F'|' '$NF == "apple" {print}'  sometextfile.txt  > Newfile.txt
```

Using `|` as the field separator, for each line of `sometextfile.txt` if the last field (`$NF`) equals "apple", print the whole line.  Redirect output to `Newfile.txt`

If you want to test for a specific column rather than the last column, use `$n` where n is the column number.  In this example, `$NF` is equivalent to `$7`, and `$6` would contain `fffffff`

Comment: I am sorry, there shouldn't be '|' at front. Updated my question

Answer (score 2):

The original question asked for a `grep` solution. To find the last column, search for a word which does not have the delimiter `[^|]+` forward to end-of-line `$`:

```
grep -Eo "[^|]+$" infile.txt
```

Output:

```
column7
apple
```

Answer (score 1):

The straight solution is to anchor your expression at the end with a `$`:

```
grep "|apple$" sometextfile.txt > Newfile.txt
```

If this doesn't find the lines, the typical reason is a DOS-formatted text file with trailing carriage returns at the line endings. You can catch that case by allowing trailing non-printable characters at the end (supposing your regex support `\s`):

```
grep "|apple\s*$" sometextfile.txt > Newfile.txt
```

Comment: for some reason it does not work

Comment: The typical reason for this would be a DOS-formatted text file with a hidden carriage return at the end. Could that be?